# How do I get a for loop to only disply the outputs one time while using substring

Tags: c#-4.0

The loop keeps repeating the output for the entire span of the word.

I tried initiating the console.write on the inside and outside the loop. I also tried changing the values of the incrementor and the substring.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a word.");
            string userWord = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", userWord);
            Console.WriteLine();

            userWord.ToLower();
            char[] wordArray = userWord.ToArray();


            for (int i = 0; i <= wordArray.Length; i++)
            {
                string theLetter = userWord.Substring(i, 1);

                //theLetter = theLetter.ToLower();
                string rebuilt = new string(wordArray);

                if (wordArray[i] == 'a' || wordArray[i] == 'e' || wordArray[i] == 'i' || wordArray[i] == 'o' || wordArray[i] == 'u')
            {
                    wordArray[i] = '$';

                }


                Console.WriteLine("Your word is now: {0}", rebuilt);
                Console.WriteLine("The total number of letters in your word is {0}", userWord.Length);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

the console.write should display it's output only once.

Comment: Have you considered moving your Cosole.WriteLine() OUT of the for loop?

Comment: I tried it both inside and outside. when I move it outside I get an error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length'

Comment: try the "-1" after the array lenght, array is 0 index ..  (int i = 0; i <= wordArray.Length -1; i++)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier but it seems that it just effectively removes the = sign in the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to move your Console.WriteLine outside the loop. Also, your loop condition needs to be changed to avoid the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.Length; i++)
```

There is one more error in your code. You are converting userWord to lower case, but you are not storing the result.

```
userWord.ToLower();
```

Above line needs to be replaced with

```
userWord = userWord.ToLower();
```

**Complete Code**

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word.");
string userWord = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", userWord);
Console.WriteLine();
    
userWord = userWord.ToLower();
char[] wordArray = userWord.ToArray();
    
for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.Length; i++)
{
        if (wordArray[i] == 'a' || wordArray[i] == 'e' || wordArray[i] == 'i' || wordArray[i] == 'o' || wordArray[i] == 'u')
        {
            wordArray[i] = '$';
    
        }
 }
    
var rebuildWord = new string(wordArray);
Console.WriteLine("Your word is now: {0}", rebuildWord);
Console.WriteLine("The total number of letters in your word is {0}", userWord.Length);
```

Just for your information, you could achieve the same using Regex as well.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word.");
string userWord = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", userWord);
Console.WriteLine();
    
    
var rebuildWord = Regex.Replace(userWord,@"[aeiouAEIOU]","$");
    

Console.WriteLine("Your word is now: {0}", rebuildWord);
Console.WriteLine("The total number of letters in your word is {0}", userWord.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the userWord line of code earlier today (I should have edited it here as well). I wish I could mark 2 correct. I'm learning as much as I can on my own and everyone here makes things more palatable.

Answer (score 1):

This is just simple. You should check if the loop is in final iteration before printing.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a word.");
        string userWord = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", userWord);
        Console.WriteLine();

        userWord.ToLower();
        char[] wordArray = userWord.ToArray();


        for (int i = 0; i <= wordArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string theLetter = userWord.Substring(i, 1);

            //theLetter = theLetter.ToLower();
            string rebuilt = new string(wordArray);

            if (wordArray[i] == 'a' || wordArray[i] == 'e' || wordArray[i] == 'i' || wordArray[i] == 'o' || wordArray[i] == 'u')
            {
                wordArray[i] = '$';

            }
            if(i==userWord.Length)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Your word is now: {0}", rebuilt);
            Console.WriteLine("The total number of letters in your word is {0}", userWord.Length);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ouch, That got right by me.  I understand now. I was playing with a similar code block a week ago and I had a similar problem. My second "if statement" was outside the loop. I guess it too a second screw up for me to learn. Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome @haberjin